# AttributeError: module 'awkward' has no attribute 'util'

Tags: python, module, awkward-array

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import awkward
import uproot_methods
```

The version of pandas is 2.1.1, and the version of numpy is 1.23.1, and the version of awkward is 0.9.0, and the uproot_methods is 0.8.0. The error message would become ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awkward.array.jagged' if I install the newer version of awkward. I don't know what is wrong?

Can anyone tell me where should I change?

Comment: I don't seen code that would raise this exception. Please got a minimal reproducible example and the full error traceback!

Comment: perhaps a failed `pip install`, but the code given works fine... the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

**uproot_methods 0.8.0 requires awkward >= 1.0.0**, but you have awkward 0.9.0 installed.

And awkward 1.0 refactored and renamed some modules, **awkward.array.jagged** was renamed to **awkward.JaggedArray**